# What is the string representation of a bytes object really and how to get back the bytes object?

Tags: python, string, encoding, utf-8

I have some text encoded to bytes using `utf-8` encoding. When processing this text I incautiously used `str()` to make it a Unicode string because I assumed this would automatically decode the bytes object with the right encoding. This, however, is not the case. For example:

```
a = "عجائب"
a_bytes = a.encode(encoding="utf-8")
b = str(a_bytes)
```

yields

```
b = "b'\\xd8\\xb9\\xd8\\xac\\xd8\\xa7\\xd8\\xa6\\xd8\\xa8'"
```

which is not what I expected.
According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)

> If neither encoding nor errors is given, str(object) returns `type(object).__str__(object)`, [...].

So my question is: What is the implemented string representation of a bytes object in Python and can I recreate my original Unicode string from it in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives you a string containing the string representation of a bytes object:

```
>>> a = "عجائب"
>>> a_bytes = a.encode(encoding="utf-8")
>>> a_bytes
b'\xd8\xb9\xd8\xac\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa6\xd8\xa8'
>>> str(a_bytes)
"b'\\xd8\\xb9\\xd8\\xac\\xd8\\xa7\\xd8\\xa6\\xd8\\xa8'"
```

Meaning, you have a valid *literal* representing a `bytes`. You can parse that literal again to an actual `bytes` using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(str(a_bytes))
b'\xd8\xb9\xd8\xac\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa6\xd8\xa8'
```

This is again the same as `a_bytes`. You can properly decode those to a `str` again, either using `.decode`, or by using the `encoding` parameter of `str`:

```
>>> str(a_bytes, 'utf-8')
'عجائب'
>>> a_bytes.decode('utf-8')
'عجائب'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `str()` and pass it as an argument a bytes variable, it converts from bytes to string. If you want to decode from `utf-8` bytes to the original string, you need to use `decode()` function and specify the initial coding method:

```
a = "عجائب"
a_bytes = a.encode(encoding="utf-8")
b = str(a_bytes)

print(b)
print(a_bytes)
print(a_bytes.decode("utf-8")) #Prints decoded string from bytes
```

**Output:**

```
b'\xd8\xb9\xd8\xac\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa6\xd8\xa8'
b'\xd8\xb9\xd8\xac\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa6\xd8\xa8'
عجائب
```

Comment: Add also `print(a_bytes)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You wrote: "[...], it converts bytes to string." I am aware of this. However, the gist of my question is: What is this conversion in detail and how to reverse it?